# Smooth mouse move parallax

Tags: jquery, css, canvas, parallax, mousemove

I want to achieve a gradual decay effect on the parallax when the mouse moves like the one on the following website

http://brightmedia.pl/

I tried the following which brings about the parallaxing just fine but it stop as soon as the mouse movement stops. How do i give it an additional velocity?

```
$('body').live('mousemove', function(e){
    var xPos = e.pageX;
    var yPos = e.pageY;

    $('#pointer-position').html("x: "xPos+"<br>y: "+yPos);

    $('#circle-1').css({
        marginLeft: -xPos/2
    });

    $('#circle-2').css({
        marginLeft: -yPos/3
    });
});
```

For example, in canvas, you provide 'vx' and give it a negative '-=1' for the decay to take place on every frame refresh. but since frames aren't in the scene with normal 'divs', adding 'vx' is out of the question.

Using jquery animate, if the mouse is in motion the element does not move till the mouse stops completely and only then it animates gradually to the final position.

Using css transition, there is a kind of a 'hesitation' before the element actually moves and only completes its motion when the moves stops completely.